# How to tunnel via SSH correctly?

Tags: linux, mysql, ssh

I have a problem tunneling a ssh connection to a remote server to use Mysql.

I try:

```
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 root@vps1
```

and works perfectly! (I tested the connection using Mysql WorkBench)

BUt if i do:

```
ssh root@vps1tunnel
```

I CAN connect but Mysql WorkBench can't connect to the remote server using the tunnel.

These are the zones in my ssh_config

```
Host vps1 
    HostName        1.1.1.1 
        Port            3000 
        IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/%r 


Host vps1tunnel 
        HostName        1.1.1.1 
        Port            3000 
        IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/%r 
        # MySQL 
        LocalForward    localhost:3306 1.1.1.1:3306
```

So now I would like to "CONVERT":

```
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 root@vps1
```

in a **ssh_config zone**

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want

```
LocalForward 3306 localhost:3306
```

Because, as with the `-L` option, the 'remote' address in the `LocalForward` option is relative to the SSH server, not the client.